# How to debug backbone js project using WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Project structure:

[image: This is the structure of the project]

Tomcat config:

[image: This is the Tomcat config]

I can start the server by external Tomcat. I move the project to WebStorm IDE, but I can not debug it in WebStorm.

How can I configure WebStorm's debugger?

Answer (score 1):

- Create a [JavaScript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.3/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) run configuration with your server address specified as URL
- start your server as you usually do it
- Press **Debug** to debug the configuration above
  See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.3/debugging-javascript-in-chrome.html#d45288e154